# Plotting Probablity Distribution function in R

Tags: function, probability, distribution

I wanted to plot the probability distribution function (pdf) of the a list of ensemble change values.list of probable likelihood for each ensemble is also available.
for example i have the data as given below
Change_list = [0.5, 1.0, 0.75, 0.15, -05, 1.5]
likelihood_List = [0.1, 0.05, 0.24, 0.56, 0.09, 0.10]

Please describe how to plot the pdf of the such dataset.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: ggplot?  Worry about the plot before you concern yourself about saving it to a PDF.  http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Output_to_a_file/

Comment: @duffymo I don't think the OP refers to portable document format but indeed the probability distribution function / probability density function

Comment: My mistake.  I believe you're correct.